# Keep Fragment context menu after rotation from Android ICS native

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to keep displaying of context menu of Fragment after rotation (in handset).

Simple situation is

- Wireless & networks -> VPN -> (Add one profile) -> (long touch to make context menu) -> 
  (rotate)

How can I keep that? `android:orientation`, `setRetainInstance` was not a answer to my testing